# FFmpeg use previous text size

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

After drawing a text, I'd like to use `geq` to make the box corners rounded.
Currently, I'm simply trying to draw a box around the text, to see if I can use the text dimensions for subsequent filters

```sh
ffplay -f lavfi -i color=black:600x200 \
-vf "drawtext=text='my text':fontsize=84:fontcolor=white:x=0:y=0:box=1:boxcolor=cyan,\
drawbox=0:0:200:60:red"
```

I tried using `text_w` and `text_h` but it didn't work

```sh
ffplay -f lavfi -i color=black:600x200 \
-vf "drawtext=text='my text':fontsize=84:fontcolor=white:x=0:y=0:box=1:boxcolor=cyan,\
drawbox=0:0:text_w:text_h:red"
```

Error

```
Error when evaluating the expression 'text_w'.
```

I need the text size to apply the rounded rectangle, I also need it for other cases where I want to overlay an icon after the text

Can it be done using FFmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround

Draw the text in debug mode

```sh
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -f lavfi -i color=black:100x100 -frames:v 1 \
-vf "drawtext=text='my text':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white:x=0:y=0:box=1:boxcolor=cyan" \
-f null -
```

It will output something like this which I can parse and use elsewhere

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x7fc1c3704c00] n:0 t:0.000000 text_w:138 text_h:33 x:0 y:0
```